# Assembly return in 64 bits a sum of two numbers of 32 bits

Tags: assembly, x86, sum, nasm

A + B (both of 32 bits).
The function will return a value of 64 bits
What i have to do ?

Comment: _What i have to do?_ Specify architecture and show what you got. In general, extend the operands to 64 bits and add them.

Comment: That's my question. How i extend the operands to 64 bits? The architecture is x86

Comment: 2 32 bit numbers result in a worst case 33 bit number, just sign extend from there.   the carry flag for the 32 bit add will show you what to put in the other 32 bits either all ones or all zeros.  that is probably defeating the exercise which I bet is leading into add followed by add with carry...

Comment: Is your code 32 or 64 bit? Have you looked at the instruction set reference? Also are your numbers signed or unsigned? Which assembler are you using?

Comment: My code is 32, unsigned numbers! In NASM

Answer (score 2):

Assuming input on the stack and result in `edx`:`eax` as per the normal conventions:

```
xor edx, edx       ; high dword
mov eax, [esp + 4] ; 1st arg
add eax, [esp + 8] ; add 2nd arg
adc edx, 0         ; handle carry
ret
```

Comment: Or save a byte with `adc edx, edx`, since it's already zeroed.  Harder to read the source, though.  Or `setc dl` may be faster on Intel CPUs (where `adc` decodes to two uops), but only if you don't use edx right away (partial-register penalty on pre-haswell).